How to build lens expression dynamically?
I have the following code snippet that reads a value specified by a lens (lens-aeson) expression:
import           Control.Lens    ((^?))
import           Data.Aeson      (Value)
import           Data.Aeson.Key  (fromString)
import           Data.Aeson.Lens (key)
import           Data.Text       (pack)

-- >>> readValue
-- Just (String "value")
readValue :: Maybe Value
readValue = json ^? path
  where
    path = key (fromString "key") . key (fromString "of") . key (fromString "interest")
    json = pack "{\"key\": {\"of\": {\"interest\": \"value\"}}}"

Now I want to build the path expression dynamically from a configuration by passing a list ["key","of","interest"] to readValue.
How can I create the path dynamically from the list?

Something like this, I guess:
readValue = json ^? _Value.path
  where
    path = foldr (.) id [key (fromString t) | t <- ["key", "of", "interest"]]
    json = pack "{\"key\": {\"of\": {\"interest\": \"value\"}}}"

You can fuse the foldr and list comprehension manually if you feel strongly about it.

The original solution failed for me because of the higher-rank nature of key. I've edited it with a list comprehension which seems to work correctly.

@K.A.Buhr Strange. It worked for me. I wonder what differs in our setups.

It looks like it's the DeepSubsumption extension introduced in 9.2.4 that's enabled by Haskell98 for compatibility reasons, but disabled for other language defaults.  (And with NoDeepSubsumption, the original doesn't compile.)

Great, this works for me. Thanks Daniel Wagner and K.A. Buhr. I am working with GHC 9.6.5 and the language edition GHC2021. Maybe this information is helpful for you @Daniel Wagner.
